# Google Calendar Events Response is Empty

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-authentication, authsub

We are fetching google calendar events through OAuth2 tokens with Google Calendar API V3 to our customers, but for some of customers' calendar getting empty response. We got empty response for the same calendar in Google OAuth Playground.

```
{
  "nextPageToken": "CjkKK2xwamMycHJ2MDU2cGp2YFxcmY3OXRtNTg0XzIwMTQwMjEyVDA0MzAwMFoYASCAgMDEtcaFoBQaDQgAEgAY2M-X7qfLvAI=", 
  "kind": "calendar#events", 
  "defaultReminders": [
    {
      "minutes": 30, 
      "method": "popup"
    }
  ], 
  "items": [], 
  "updated": "2014-02-14T09:32:57.943Z", 
  "summary": "TEST", 
  "etag": "\"TuPKiPtcUnaxp3U8BefUMu26Bg/LWnnxrAP6L1-mgjBDhy0rIebYaE\"", 
  "timeZone": "Asia/Calcutta", 
  "accessRole": "owner"
}
```

But when the same user is authenticated through AuthSub, it is fetching the events list. Is anyone having the same issue? Any help would be appreciated.

TIA,
Riyaz.A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't set pageToken to the event instance

```
Calendar.Events.List events = service.build().events().list(gCalId);
```

But when we try model Events instance, we able to set `pageToken` and got response too

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events events = service.build().events().list(gCalId).setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried actually calling the API with the `nextPageToken`? Usually the client libraries do this auto pagination for you, but in this case you may need to manually make the call. In general, you should plan on calling next pages until `nextPageToken` is empty or not present.

This might just be an weirdness with the API.

Comment: Hi Arun, Could I add nextPageToken even for maxResults? How could I retrieve events of maximum of n numbers with or without nexPageToken?.